# Is there a term for "if" statements not intended as conditions, like "if you want"

Tags: terminology, semantics, figure-of-speech

I might say, "There is food in the fridge, if you want, Fred."

I do not mean that food in the fridge will only exist if Fred wants it to exist.

I mean, "There is food in the fridge, [which I mention so that you know about it] if you want [to get yourself any]."

Since I first noticed this sort of phrase, I notice variation on it all the time. Is there a term for this sort of "condition"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called Biscuit Conditionals. Several sources say the term was coined in Austin (1956), though I haven't checked the original paper.

Austin, J. L. (1956) Ifs and cans. Proceedings of the British Academy 42, 109–132

Comment: THank you: I hadn't heard that expression before.

Comment: Thanks! Happy New Year